# What is the connection between setVisibility and layout_weight in Linear Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have a `LinearLayout` with three children in it, two `RecyclerView`s and an `ImageView`. In the code based on some condition I enable and disable these children using `setVisibility()`.

```
public void onNotificationPriorityMixChanged(int mix) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationPriorityMixChanged() called with: mix = [" + mix + "]");
    switch (mix) {
        case MIX_BOTTOM_ONLY: {
            topListView.setVisibility(GONE);
            bottomListView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            spacer.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        break;
        case MIX_TOP_ONLY: {
            topListView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            bottomListView.setVisibility(GONE);
            spacer.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        break;
        case MIX_NONE: {
            topListView.setVisibility(GONE);
            bottomListView.setVisibility(GONE);
            spacer.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        break;
        case MIX_BOTH: {
            topListView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            bottomListView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            spacer.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }
        break;
        default:
    }
}
```

The layout file is has a `LinearLayout` with a first `RecyclerView` (topListView) followed by the `ImageView` (spacer) followed by again a `RecyclerView` (bottomListView) in it.

The problem is that I cannot get only one child view to occupy whole parent when other two are disabled.
My question is that should I use the `layout_weight` attribute in XML or dynamically. and can anyone tell me what is the connection between using `setVisibility()` and `layout_weight` attribute, if there is any?

Comment: add your xml code

Comment: try removing the weigh sum in your linearLayout.

Comment: @GauravChauhan the XML is as posted below in answers

Comment: @AngelKoh I didn't use `weightSum` in `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Set the `layout_height` of your `RecyclerViews` to `0dp` (for Vertical `LinearLayout`)

I have tested this working fine

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

for **hiding** any view use `.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

for **showing** any view use `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Comment: It worked without using the `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to `match_parent`  this is what I used:                                `<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/notifications_listview_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />`

Comment: Still I'm not clear about the `setVisibility` and `layout_height`. How does the bottom view occupy the upper space in linear layout when the top two views are set to `GONE` and viceversa, where both the recycler view has same `layout_weight`

Comment: because layout is dividing into equal parts and when layout has only one part then it occupies all the space.