# In android application RecyclerView view show only half of the phone with

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Here in my activity_main.xml|
in my android RecyclerView show only half of the screen, I'm not able to find out the mistake. Help me guys. I was used different layout like relativelayout, constraintlayout, linearlayout. but I was getting only half of the screen RecyclerView with size.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryHint="Search Distributors..." />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/search"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGet"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="get" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here I attach my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.admin.recyclerview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private List<Model> models;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
        public SearchView searchView;
        private Button button;
        private RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            searchView = findViewById(R.id.search);
            button = findViewById(R.id.btnGet);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    List<Model> models1 = recyclerViewAdapter.getList();
                    System.out.println("final order list "+new Gson().toJson(models1));
                }
            });
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    if (recyclerViewAdapter != null) {
                        recyclerViewAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            //recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            models = new ArrayList<>();
            models.add(new Model("rajesh"));
            models.add(new Model("deva"));
            models.add(new Model("merlin"));
            models.add(new Model("antony"));
            models.add(new Model("giri"));
            models.add(new Model("guru"));
            System.out.println("get the position " + 
            models.get(0).getName());
            System.out.println("json view "+new Gson().toJson(models));
            recyclerViewAdapter = new 
            RecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), models);

            recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

        }
    }
```

Here i bellow attach my adapter class

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    public Context context;
    private List<Model> modelList;
    private List<Model> myfilterList;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Model> modelList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.modelList = modelList;
        this.myfilterList = modelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, null);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {
        Model model = myfilterList.get(i);
        myViewHolder.llMain.setTag(i);
        myViewHolder.textView.setText(model.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myfilterList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                String text = constraint.toString();
                if (text.isEmpty()) {
                    myfilterList = modelList;
                } else {
                    ArrayList<Model> filterable = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Model model : modelList) {
                        System.out.println("check equal " + model.getName() 
                         + "   " + text);
                        if (model.getName().toLowerCase().contains(text)) {
                            filterable.add(model);
                        }
                    }
                    myfilterList = filterable;
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = myfilterList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                myfilterList = (ArrayList<Model>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        Button btnAdd, btnMinus;
        LinearLayout llMain;

        MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            btnAdd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
            btnMinus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
            llMain = itemView.findViewById(R.id.llMain);

            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = (Integer) llMain.getTag();
                    System.out.println("linear layout position details 
                    "+pos);
                    myfilterList.add(pos+1, new Model("dummy"));
                    notifyItemChanged(pos+1);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public List<Model> getList()
    {
        return myfilterList;
    }
}
```

Here I bellow attach my item xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Items"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Items"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: So you are saying the recyclerView is occupying half of the phone's screen width?

Comment: Use this  **`View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items,viewGroup,false);`** instead of this `View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_items, null);`

Comment: THANKS for your replay. i was changed all layouts in relative layout. i solve my problem. but i cannot achieve in constraint layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try changing the `RecyclerView` element inside your `activity_main.xml` file with the following, remove `center_in_parent` and change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryHint="Search Distributors..." />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGet"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="get" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit 1 - Using `ConstraintLayout`, since after the `RecyclerView` you'd also like to display the button, you will need the `ConstraintLayout` inside the `NestedScrollView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryHint="Search Distributors..." />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGet"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="get" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: THANKS for your replay. i was changed all layouts in relative layout. i solve my problem. but i cannot achieve in constraint layout.

Comment: In ConstraintLayout, change `android:layout_height="0dp"` and add these two lines - `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` & 
        `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. in recyclerview items.xml  not correctly positioned when i was using constrained.

Comment: Give me a moment to update my answer with the solution to your above problem.

Comment: I've updated the answer, now uses `ConstraintLayout` to display the search view on the top and button at the bottom after the recyclerView, Hope this helps.

Comment: @rajeshdeva Please accept the answer if this solution worked for you :)

Comment: @ hsm59 i was give a positive vote. how to do accept the answer.? . sorry i am new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have privileges to add a comment, hence posting it here. Sorry in advance.
Your question is not quite clear, do you want your `RecyclerView` to occupy the whole screen(i.e. `parent`). If that's the case, With `LinearLayout` I guess if you add an attribute `android:layout_weight` in your `RecyclerView` will solve the problem. 
Here's what the discription for the attribute on developer.android site:

**`LinearLayout` also supports assigning a weight to individual children with the `android:layout_weight` attribute. This attribute assigns an "importance" value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen. A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight. Default weight is zero.**

Hope this link helps https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear

Also there's this question already asked by me : [What is the connection between setVisibility and layout_weight in Linear Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061252/what-is-the-connection-between-setvisibility-and-layout-weight-in-linear-layout/53061544?noredirect=1#comment93054119_53061544)

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: THANKS for your replay. i was changed all layouts in relative layout. i solve my problem. but i cannot achieve in constraint layout.

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter where you are inflating the item in onCreateViewHolder, use this code block:

```
View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.itemLayout, null, false);
RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rootView.setLayoutParams(lp);
return new RecyclerViewHolder(rootView);
```

Comment: THANKS for your replay. i was changed all layouts in relative layout. i solve my problem. but i cannot achieve in constraint layout.

Comment: was facing same issue while using databinding dnt knw why but this hack solved by issue thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    items.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/llMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="fdfsfsdfsd"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add Items"/>
                <Button
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvName"
                    android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add Items"/>        
        </RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryHint="Search Distributors..." />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGet"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="get" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```